# How to update datagridview based on its Id?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, datagridview

I'm developing software in which I have a datagridview in wpf in which I have successfully done with inserting the values through fields in datagridview when clicked on insert button. But when I'm clicking on update I'm getting following exception .Find the screenshot of error below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFXpL.jpg

The code that have been tried by myself is below :

```
public partial class Machine : Window
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\ATS\ATS Data Management System\ATS Data Management System\ATSDataManagementsystemDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    public Machine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
        BindMyData();
    }
    public void BindMyData()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblmachines", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            da.Fill(ds);
            gridmachine.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }


    private void btninsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblmachines VALUES('" + txtid.Text + "','" + txtsalesdate.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtpartname.Text + "','" + txtprice.Text + "','" + txtquantity.Text + "','" + txttotalamount.Text + "','" + paidpending.Text + "','" + txtpaidamount.Text + "','" + txtpendingamount.Text + "','" + txtcreditamountpaid.Text + "','" + txtpaiddate.Text + "','" + txtpaymentmode.Text + "')", conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            BindMyData();
        }
    }

    private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblmachines SET SalesDate='" +txtsalesdate.Text+ "',Name='" +txtname.Text+"',Part Name='"+txtpartname.Text+"',Price="+txtprice.Text+",Quantity="+txtquantity.Text+",Total Amount="+txttotalamount.Text+",PaymentStatus='"+paidpending.Text+"',Paid Amount="+txtpaidamount.Text+",Pending Amount="+txtpendingamount.Text+",Credit Amount Paid="+txtcreditamountpaid.Text+",Paid Date='"+txtpaiddate.Text+"',Payment Mode='"+txtpaymentmode.Text+"'WHERE Id=" + txtid.Text + "", conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            BindMyData();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want the data to get updated and show up in data grid view but its not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `Part Name`,`Paid Amount`, `Pending Amount` and `Credit Amount Paid` column, i think the error is the column name

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblmachines SET SalesDate='" +txtsalesdate.Text+ "',Name='" +txtname.Text+"',Part Name='"+txtpartname.Text+"',Price="+txtprice.Text+",Quantity="+txtquantity.Text+",Total Amount="+txttotalamount.Text+",PaymentStatus='"+paidpending.Text+"',Paid Amount="+txtpaidamount.Text+",Pending Amount="+txtpendingamount.Text+",Credit Amount Paid="+txtcreditamountpaid.Text+",Paid Date='"+txtpaiddate.Text+"',Payment Mode='"+txtpaymentmode.Text+"'WHERE Id=" + txtid.Text + "", conn);
```

You should also add space in the `WHERE`
Show your table structure

Comment: Here it is screenshot of my table structure : https://imgur.com/a/g1FmpyA  @nante gwapo

Comment: Ohh i see, i think you should add space between + txtname.text +, and your other textboxes

Comment: SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblmachines SET SalesDate='"+ txtsalesdate.Text +"',Name='"+ txtname.Text +"',Part Name='"+ txtpartname.Text +"',Price='"+ txtprice.Text +"',Quantity='"+ txtquantity.Text +"',Total Amount='"+ txttotalamount.Text +"',PaymentStatus='"+ paidpending.Text +"',Paid Amount="+ txtpaidamount.Text +"',Pending Amount='"+ txtpendingamount.Text +"',Credit Amount Paid='"+ txtcreditamountpaid.Text 
 +"',Paid Date='"+ txtpaiddate.Text +"',Payment Mode='"+ txtpaymentmode.Text 
 +"'  WHERE Id=" + txtid.Text + "", conn);

Comment: Have you tried putting braces in the field name?
For example: [Part Name]='"+ txtpartname.text +"'

PS. Im not really a MSSQL user, i use MYSQL :) , but ill try to help you

Comment: Thanks its working I tried using braces around field name! Thank you !

Comment: This answer uses string concatenation to build an SQL statement. This will open your database to SQL injection. Use parameters.